# R - Correlation between 2 binary variables (BV), a BV and a continuous variable, a BV and a categorical variable, 2 categorical variables

Tags: r, correlation

Are there functions in R that help you specify variable types before calculating correlation coefficients, along with p-value? I am not able to find any such function. Please do share your inputs.

Thanks

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @zx8754 - Thank you for replying. Actually, I generally post script and sample data for reproducing any issue under consideration. But here, the only thing I know is that there is a function in R called cor() that helps you find out correlation coefficient between set of 2 variables using methods of pearson, spearman, and kendall, I don't know anything other than this. This was the reason, I posted a direct question. Hope this is fine now.